# Match multiple characters one or more times

Tags: regex, string, bash

Consider the following problem:
We have a string of random chars flowing from /dev/urandom and we want to process it in such way that we will get strings of a constant length which meet certain conditions .
For example if we run the following command 5 times we get :

```
cat /dev/urandom |tr -dc A-Z5|head -c${1:-30}
DLZEZDATSTDN55BNVDSNRFSLRKHDGR
AVCRIE5OAFBUWZZYQYQWCTAZSNMQAA
HSTFN5AQNWILXMSZCBIGREPNCFGPDM
AZJNEUQRCDYSKXMQDUHVTOFEOAYPHF
ANFDWHHZHLAGXCPKWLQESSZLEZYNDC
```

Now, these strings meet the conditions I need but only partially. 
For ex. I need that the digit 5 to appear at least 2 times but no more than 7 times in a string and any of the letters should not appear more than 10 times.
How should I customize the command above to get this result ?

Comment: Pipe it to something with regex, use regex to check you conditions.

Comment: should any debug message be outputted if some string doesn't meet the conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash solution using a function with the filter needed by OP.

#### Explanation :

*filter* is the count of character 5 appearances. I get that by removing everything on the string with *tr* except the character 5 and then counting how many chars are left.

*grep -E '(.)(.*\1){10}'* is  a standard regular expression to make sure no character is present more than 10 times.

The loop then just gets one random word after the other until all the three conditions are met. It can take a random time of course. :P

```
function GETRANDOMWORD {
    local filter=0;
    until [[ $filter -gt 1 && $filter -lt 8 && ! $( echo "$word" | grep -E '(.)(.*\1){10}') ]]
    do
        word="$( cat /dev/urandom |tr -dc A-Z5|head -c${1:-30} )"
        filter=$( echo "$word" | tr -cd '5' | wc -c )
    done
    [[ "$word" ]] && echo "$word"
}
```

#### Usage :

[image]

Comment: Could you add an explanation?

Comment: @M.Becerra Done!

Comment: @MatiasBarrios thanks a ton man , you are amazing . works very well. This community is incredible !

Answer (score 1):

With GNU **`awk`** processing:

```
awk -v FS="" '{ 
                  err=0; 
                  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) { 
                      a[$i]++; 
                      if ($i~/[A-Z]/ && a[$i]>10) { err=1; break } 
                  } 
                  if (!err && (2>a[5] || a[5]>7)) err=1 
              }
              END{ if (!err) print }' <(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Z5 | head -c30)
```

---

- `FS=""` - in this case, each individual character in the record becomes a separate field

The above will make a *random* string to be printed only if all conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks! your solution is also good, i realy appreciate it. I'll keep them both . I just pick the first answer because i understood it better . I don't have too much experience with Bash scripting, not to mention awk.